# Doxygen - Showing variables that are not variables

Tags: doxygen

After running doxygen, a php file with this line of code is shown as a variable in the documentation.

```
if($_SESSION['autenticado'] !='validado') {
    header("location: index.php");
    exit;
 }
```

And the very funny thing, is that the true variable $ menu, in the next line is set in the same line of the code before.

This is how the documentation is shown.

Variables:

```
if($_SESSION['autenticado']!='validado')    $menu = new Menu()
```

Is there any chance to fix this?This has happened in others context too, I suppose the same problem happening.

EDIT:

```
<?php
/**
  * \file
  * \brief Página de perfil do usuário <br />
  * <b>Dependências:</b><br />
  * Classes/Conecta.php<br />
  * Classes/Menu.php<br />
  * Classes/Usuario.php<br />
  * Classes/Midia.php <br />
  * Classes/Grupo.php<br />
  * session_start()
  */
if ( $_SESSION['autenticado'] !='validado') { header("location: index.php"); exit; }
 /**
  * \brief $menu Descreve um teste
  */
$menu = new Menu();
$usuario = new Usuario();
$teste = new array();
if ( $_SESSION['autenticado'] !='validado')
{
  header("location: index.php");
  exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using?

Comment: Version: 1.8.11

Comment: Does this also happen with the current version (1.8.14 or the  master version)  ? Please post a small Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing the problem and including the changes you made to the doxygen configuration file (Doxyfile)

Comment: I've updated to the last version, 1.8.15 and it still showing the if conditional as a variable in the variable scope.

Comment: Please post a small MCVE so I can try to reproduce it.

Comment: So, try to generate an output with this code:

Comment: <?php
/**
* \file  exemplo.php
* \breif Página de perfil do usuário <br />  
* <b>Dependências:</b><br />
* Classes/Conecta.php<br />
* Classes/Menu.php<br />
* Classes/Usuario.php<br />
* Classes/Midia.php <br />
* Classes/Grupo.php<br />
* session_start()
*/

if ( $_SESSION['autenticado'] !='validado') {
   header("location: index.php");
    exit;
 }
 /** 
 * \brief $menu Descreve um teste 
 */
 $menu = new Menu();
 $usuario = new Usuario();
 $teste = new array();


 if ( $_SESSION['autenticado'] !='validado') {
   header("location: index.php");
    exit;
 }
?>

Comment: Now, you just need to save file, with example.php and generate the output using Doxygen config file standard.

Comment: I added the code to the question so it is readable. The first closing was incorrect `/` instead of `*/` and there was a `\breif` instead of `\brief`. With this example I see that the part `if( $_SESSION['autenticado'] !='validado')` is shown as type with the variable.

Comment: Note also that the start of the second comment block missed a `*` at the beginning (`/*` instead of `/**`).

Comment: The code I posted here is just like what you said about the missing */. But when I put the code here, the * disappear.

Comment: I'll try another way to post the code.

Comment: Not necessary as I already included it in the question.

Comment: But, even after I made the changes, the output still the same.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see you have included the code in the question.,

Comment: the output still the same, it could be a bug of Doxygen? This is happing in others files too, with for exampe the for command.

Comment: As far as I can see it is a bug in doxygen, maybe best that you submit an issue in the doxygen issue tracer: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new

Comment: Made it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Doxygen issue https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/6646